# Why can't I create the RealTime Update inside the input?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my Facebook clone input to be updated in real-time.

#Real-time Update inside the input, just like you can see on Facebook

I expect the result to be like this,

[image],

Mycode

[image],

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Post CODE, not pictures of code

Comment: There is no code that updates anything. You just swap between not flex and flex. The insertion of the value already happend when the script loaded. It is not guessable what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Add a onchange event and set the value on every change

Answer (score -3):

In the context of Java and HTML, RealTime Updates typically involve asynchronous communication with a server using technologies such as WebSocket or AJAX. The nature of RealTime Updates necessitates a separate mechanism, distinct from an input field.

1. **Concurrency and Responsiveness:**
   RealTime Updates often require continuous communication with a server, which can involve long-running tasks. Embedding this process within an input field could lead to unresponsiveness, as user interactions would be competing for resources with the ongoing RealTime Update operations.
2. **Separation of Concerns:**
   Design principles, such as separation of concerns, dictate that different aspects of an application should have distinct responsibilities. User inputs and RealTime Updates represent separate concerns in terms of functionality and implementation. Embedding RealTime Updates within an input would violate this principle, making the code less modular and maintainable.
3. **User Experience:**
   RealTime Updates often aim to enhance the user experience by providing live and dynamic information. Placing such functionality within an input could lead to confusion and may not align with conventional user expectations, potentially hindering the overall usability of the application.

To implement RealTime Updates in Java and HTML, consider employing technologies like WebSocket for bidirectional communication between the client and server. This allows for efficient, low-latency data exchange without compromising the responsiveness or structure of your user interface.

Comment: Bro, you don't need to ask AI for me, it doesn't work.

Comment: [ChatGPT is banned at SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)